# How to explain a particular property of the second-to-last bits of primes?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Assuming that $i \geq 0$, let $p_i$ denote an $i$-th prime: $p_0 = 2, p_1 = 3, \ldots$ Then $b_i$ denotes the second-to-last bit of $p_i$, i.e. $b_i = \left\lfloor p_i/2 \right\rfloor \bmod 2.$

The sequences $B_0$ and $B_1$ are constructed by the following algorithm: if $b_i$ is equal to $i \bmod 2$, append $b_i$ to $B_0$; otherwise (i.e. if $b_i$ is not equal to $i \bmod 2$), append $b_i$ to $B_1$. Thus $$\begin{array}{l}
B_0 = 
1010101101010101010101101010101010011001001111001101001011001010\ldots,\\
B_1 = 
1101010101011001011010101100101010101010010101011101010101010101\ldots
\end{array}$$

Basically, both of these sequences are $\ldots1010\ldots$, slightly interspersed with runs of two or more identical bits. For example, the first $10^6$ bits of $B_1$ do not even contain ten consecutive zeros. What is the explanation of this phenomenon?

Comment: FYI, a couple of fairly closely related questions are [Unexpected autocorrelations in sequence of primes modulo 4](https://mathoverflow.net/q/408291/129887) and [Word complexity of primes mod 4](https://mathoverflow.net/q/195995/129887).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the phenomena you observe are explained more by the way you construct $B_0$ and $B_1$ than by the properties of primes (though properties of primes seem to play a role). If we suppose instead that $b_i$ were random, obtained by a coin flip, it's easy to see that for each bit of $B_0$ or $B_1$, the probability that the next bit is the same is $\frac{1}{3}$, and the probability that the next bit is different is $2/3$.

Indeed, say $b_i \equiv i \mod 2$ for some $i$, so at time $i$ we have just added $b_i$ to $B_0$.

Then if the next $k-1$ bits are not congruent to their position mod $2$, followed by the $k$th bit congruent to its position, $i+k$, mod $2$, we next append the bit $i+k \mod 2$ to $B_0$. This occurs with probability $\frac{1}{2^k}$, and in each sequence this occurs for exactly one value of $k$.

So we get a different bit with probability $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{2^5} + \dots = \frac{2}{3}$, and the same bit with probability $\frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^4} + \frac{1}{2^6} + \dots = \frac{1}{3}$. The $B_1$ case is identical.

So the probability of getting $10$ consecutive zeroes starting at any given point is $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{3^9}$. However, the length of time we expect to take before seeing the first run of $10$ consecutive zeroes is a little longer than the inverse of that, $3^{10}-1=59048$, by a classical argument.

So we waited about 17 times longer than one would expect to find a run of ten zeroes. (But you had 4 choices to pick to find such a long run without zeroes). That's not completely surprising, but it's a lot less strange than in the naive random model, where the expected wait time is $2^{11}-1$, so you would have waited about $489$ times longer than expected.

---

More generally, if we replace $b_i$ with a Markov chain with probability of taking the same value on adjacent steps $p$, then the probability that $B_0$ takes the same value on adjacent steps should be $$p^2 + p^2(1-p)^2 + p^2 (1-p)^4 + \dots = \frac{ p^2}{ 1- (1-p)^2} = \frac{p^2 }{ 2p -p^2} = \frac{p}{ 2-p}$$ since to get two of the same bit in $B_0$, $b_i$ must be same-same or same-different-different-same or same-different-different-different-different-same.

To explain $\frac{ p}{2-p} = \frac{1}{2} - .28 = .22$ as in dvitek's analysis, we need $p= \frac{2}{ 1/.22 +1} =.361$, i.e. there is a discrepancy of about $.14$ to explain in the more natural statistic of how often two adjacent primes have distinct second-to-last bits.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, Will, you're saying that I should be taking $d_0 = 1/6$ "for free" from the construction of $B_0$ and $B_1$, and then I get $d_1\approx 0.12$ presumably from small-prime behavior (à la LOS's value of $0.07$ at a larger scale than my experiment)?  I must confess I didn't put a huge amount of effort into understanding the artificial-looking definitions of $B_0$ and $B_1$ beyond reproducing the output.

Comment: @dvitek I'm not sure what you mean by $d_0$ and $d_1$, but yes, I'm saying the weird construction explains a lot of the bias and there's a smaller amount for the LO-S  phenomenon to explain. See my edit for an estimate of how much is left.

Comment: Whoops, I meant that the observed $d \approx 0.28$ should be written as $d = d_0 + d_1$, but I was mixing the $B_0$/$B_1$ analysis versus the consecutive-primes analysis.  At any rate, the highest-order term in Conjecture 1.2 of LO-S corresponds to $p \approx 0.398$ (here $x \approx p_{10^5} \approx 1.3\times10^6$ in my data), so this is most of the way to the range of $d$ necessary to explain the discrepancy.  At this point we probably start to care about longer-range effects...

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is all that unexpected given [work of Lemke Oliver and Soundararajan](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.03720) on residues of consecutive primes.  (I realize that the first word of that paper's title is "Unexpected", but I don't care.)  Note that John Omielan's first link in the comments points (eventually) to this paper.

---

Let's look at the run statistics of the first 49,981 bits of $B_0$, corresponding to about half of the first 100,000 primes.  There are runs of equal consecutive bits of lengths 1 through 7, and the counts of these runs are, respectively, $$(27261, 7710, 1771, 390, 67, 13, 2).$$

Now consider a Markov process with states {0,1} and transition matrix \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}-d & \frac{1}{2}+d \\ \frac{1}{2}+d & \frac{1}{2}-d\end{pmatrix} for some parameter $d \in [-1/2, 1/2]$.  We should expect shorter runs for larger $d$, and longer runs for smaller $d$.  If we take $d = 0.28$, we get the following counts for runs of length 1 through 11, averaged over 100 samples: $$(30378.2, 6700.82, 1472.6, 324.16, 71.42, 16.01, 3.7, 0.75, 0.15, 0.02, 0.01).$$  This looks like a decent fit to the observed values, if perhaps a bit too low on medium-length runs and too high elsewhere.

---

I'm not sure what value of $d$ is realistic here: Lemke Oliver and Soundararajan have (conjecturally) asymptotically correct expressions, but they're studying a slightly different problem.  More specifically, if we look at mod 4 residues of the first $10^6$ primes, their data suggest $d \approx 0.07$ is a reasonable guess for their problem.  For smaller primes $d$ should be larger, but your $B_0$/$B_1$ setup is artificial enough so as to make their methods significantly harder to apply.  (**EDIT:** it seems like the bulk of this $d$ term is due to the definitions of $B_0$ and $B_1$; see Will Sawin's answer.)

More broadly, the shape mismatch in the data suggests (unsurprisingly) that there are longer-range effects going on than those captured by the Markov process modelling.  I expect spending some quality time with Lemke Oliver and Soundararajan and thinking about the prime tuples conjecture should give you better explanations here.

Comment: Even the Spanish Inquisition ceases to be unexpected after the first time